# "Don't play soundPool because of a recording" on LG phone

Tags: android, playback, soundpool, recording, audiorecord

I have an app where it records via AudioRecord  and play sounds at the same time via: 
play(int soundID, float leftVolume, float rightVolume, int priority, int loop, float rate)

The AudioRecord will last about a minute, and during this there will be several short sounds from SoundPool lasting about 2 seconds each. All sounds are pre-loaded.

And everything works as expected on devices such as (e.g. Galaxy S3; Nexus 7 device). But when testing the exact same code on an LG-P875 (probably as modern as other 2 devices and running Android 4.1+), I get the message: "Don't play soundPool because of a recording". This comes from a SoundPool filter.

The same code for SoundPool, without also recording, running on a LG-P875, plays sounds fine. It is just an issue with playing SoundPool and recording on a LG phone.

I'd appreciate any ideas or directions to take to find a workaround / find root source of issue. I expect there are many devices similar to LG-P875 where this error occurs.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The workaround I used was to automatically generate midi files and play them using MediaPlayer. That way with LG phones, you can record at the same time as play sounds.